# Tab host - setCurrentTab(x) works for tab but not a content [Android]

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I have created tab app.. now I am playing with screen rotation. I tried to set `tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(1)`, which should show second tab (first is 0). The point is that second tab is shown as selected, but shown content is from first tab... How can I solve that?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myCommunicator = new Communicator();
    dbAdapter = new ToDoDBAdapter(this);


    if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) 
    {
        CurrentTab = (Integer)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        createView();
    }
    else
    {
        BuildDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Updating data...", true, false);
        BuildDialog.show();
        new LoadChannels().execute();
    }

}


private void createView()
{
        tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

        Intent intent; 
        TabSpec spec;
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Channels.class);

        // TAB 1
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("kanali").setIndicator("Kanali",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_channels)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Currently.class);

        // TAB 2
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("trenutno").setIndicator("Trenutno",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_current)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Reminders.class);

        // TAB 3
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("opomniki").setIndicator("Opomniki",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_reminder)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, About.class);

        // TAB 4
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("oprogramu").setIndicator("O programu",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_about)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1); // Should always set content to second
}
```

@Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
    {
        return CurrentTab;
    }

```
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    CurrentTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
}
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Close the database
    try {
        dbAdapter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
  }

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    createView();
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why are you calling `getTabWidget()`? You should use the `setCurrentTab()` on the `tabHost` itself.

Works fine here.

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
```

Comment: Tried that before ... but same result with tabHost.setCurrentTab(1) or tanHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(1)...

Comment: @M.V. Ehhh... I use the above code in my own application for swiping (listen for events, change tab if it's a valid swipe) and it works absolutely fine. If it doesn't work for you then your problem is somewhere else in the code.

Comment: O.K. I have added code, handling the tab host... Hopefully this will help solving a problem. Tanks!

Comment: Any particular reason that entire design is pretty different from the Android tutorial on it? Mine resembles http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html quite closely, in particular the `tabHost = getTabHost();` call might be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use *setCurrentTabByTag(String tag);*  Depending upon the tag you mentioned would be the default tab, hope it helps, works (It's currectly working for [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) code!!)

```
private static final String A ="Kanali"; //required defualt tab name
.
.
.
tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag (A);
```

[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check TabHost in the debugger to be sure that all of the tabs were successfully added before you tried to set the currentTab? I had a similar issue and found that TabHost.setCurrentTab remains set to -1 if you try to reference an index that is outside of the range of tabs that were not successfully added.  This behavior is not documented in the Android documentation.